# Need success_url to vary depending on user group in CreateView

Tags: django

I have two user groups, 'Owners' and 'Employees'.  They can use the same form to enter data, but I want them to be directed to a different list view upon success. I have a working CreateView:

```
class ServiceAddBlankView(
    views.LoginRequiredMixin,
    views.FormValidMessageMixin,
    views.SetHeadlineMixin, 
    generic.CreateView
):

    form_class = ServiceForm
    headline = 'Add Service'
    form_valid_message = "Service Entered!"
    model = Service
    template_name = 'wesapp/service_add.html'
    success_url = '/wesapp/service_list/'
```

But, I want to have the success_url vary by the user group.
I want the `success_url` to be `/wesapp/service_list/` if the user group is 'Owner' and to be `/wesapp/services/` if the user group is 'Employee'.

I tried this, but it is not finding any success_url at all:

```
owner_group = Group.objects.get(name="Owner").user_set.all()
employee_group = Group.objects.get(name="Employee").user_set.all()
class ServiceAddBlankView(
    views.LoginRequiredMixin,
    views.FormValidMessageMixin,
    views.SetHeadlineMixin, 
    generic.CreateView
):

    form_class = ServiceForm
    headline = 'Add Service'
    form_valid_message = "Service Entered!"
    model = Service
    template_name = 'wesapp/service_add.html'
    if user in owner_group:
        success_url = '/wesapp/services/'
    if user in employee_group:
        success_url = '/wesapp/service_list/'
```

The error is:

```
name 'user' is not defined
```

How do I access the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access the user in the class definition as you are doing. Instead, the `CreateView` has a [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) method, which allows you to set the success view dynamically.

In the method, you can access the request with `self.request`, therefore you can access the logged in user with `self.request.user`.

```
class ServiceAddBlankView(generic.CreateView):

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Owner").exists():
            return '/wesapp/services/'
        elif self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Employee").exists():
            return '/wesapp/service_list/'
        else:
            return '/fallback/url/'
```

I've changed the query to check whether the user is in the Owner or Employee group. In your original code, you were unnecessarily loading every Owner and Employee. Note that my code is behaves slightly different if the user is an Owner **and** an Employee - if that's important, you need to change it.

Comment: Sweet!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Django's request object has access to the user.  Refer to request.user as documented here :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user